# Int.ToString("C") removes negative symbol

Tags: .net, tostring

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5.aspx, if I want to display a number as a currency, I can call .ToString() and pass a parameter, in this case "C"

However, based upon the details below which is from the MSDN site, it automatically removes the minus (-) character, meaning my value is now positive.

```
int value = -16325;   
// Display value using default ToString method.
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());            // Displays -16325 
// Display value using some standard format specifiers.
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("G"));         // Displays -16325
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C"));         // Displays ($16,325.00)
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("D"));         // Displays -16325
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("F"));         // Displays -16325.00
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N"));         // Displays -16,325.00
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("X"));         // Displays FFFFC03B
```

So, how do I keep it with the minus symbol, would I have to use the Contains("-") method and if it's true add the - back on.

Something like this code (apologies if it's coded incorrectly, but you get the idea).

```
string x = (value.ToString().Contains("-") : "-" + value.ToString("C") ?  + value.ToString("C"));
```

Comment: if you get the "-" replaced by the "(...)" as MSDN says, it is correct and it depends on the regional settings for the user in windows control panel, if user wants to see ( instead of a minus why override his/her settings?

Comment: The **brackets** are what says negative in the app's current culture

Comment: @DavidePiras  - Good question, in this case, the software has to be set up on a remote server which must be in that regional settings for our 'main' software to run, my application is just an addition to it; everyone speaks English though and for the accounts, it must show - or not!

Comment: @DaveRook you can always pass a specific culture to the `ToString`...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This depends on the value of your `CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern`. Possible values are from 0 - 15:

```
0 : ($12,345.00)
1 : -$12,345.00
2 : $-12,345.00
3 : $12,345.00-
4 : (12,345.00$)
5 : -12,345.00$
6 : 12,345.00-$
7 : 12,345.00$-
8 : -12,345.00 $
9 : -$ 12,345.00
10 : 12,345.00 $-
11 : $ 12,345.00-
12 : $ -12,345.00
13 : 12,345.00- $
14 : ($ 12,345.00)
15 : (12,345.00 $)
```

So it looks like you want to set it to `1` to get the output you are after with something like:

```
int value = -12345;

var numberFormat = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
numberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;

string numberAsCurrency = value.ToString("C", numberFormat)
```

Though, based on your comments about it being a remote server and you always want to format in a specific way it may be better to just set the culture for the whole thread to a controlled value and this will affect all subsequent `ToString()` calls on that thread:

```
int value = -12345;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
string numberAsCurrency = value.ToString("C");
```

Answer (score 8):

You can create a custom `NumberFormatInfo` from your current locale. Then you can specify it's [`CurrencyNegativePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx), for example:

```
int value = -16325;
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var mutableNfi = (NumberFormatInfo)culture.NumberFormat.Clone();
mutableNfi.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("C", mutableNfi)); // Displays (-$16,325.00)
```

Answer (score 4):

you might like to try this out

```
        Console.WriteLine((-1234).ToString("c"));
        CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        CultureInfo newCulture = new CultureInfo(currentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
        newCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
        Console.WriteLine((-1234).ToString("c"));
```

MSDN : [NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyNegativePattern Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx)  for detail...

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the localization settings of the machine. Negative Currencies in many locales is represented as `( amount )` So .net here is using that. I'm not sure how to override this. But that's what is going on here.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the culture. It uses [`NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyNegativePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx) - which in the US appears to use parentheses to indicate a negative number. (A positive number wouldn't have the parentheses.)

So you *could* clone your current `CultureInfo`, and change the `CurrencyNegativePattern` of the associated `NumberFormatInfo` - but I'd be wary of doing that. In general, you should trust that the cultural information that .NET uses is appropriate for that culture. You need to decide whether you do *want* a culture-specific representation, of course - if not, you might want to use the invariant culture.

Comment: I agree with changing it could have a negative affect, but, in my case it's for a very small report which just displays if our target profit is above or below! Thank you though, again!

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
string text = value < 0 ? "-" + (-value).ToString("C") : value.ToString("C");
```

But make sure the localization settings do not change to prevent unpredictable results (like --$ 1.00)

Comment: And now you have `-(123.45)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get the currency string, and only if it is bracketed, remove the brackets and add a "-".

```
private string ToCurrencyString(decimal amount)
{
    string c = amount.ToString("C");
    if (c.StartsWith("(") && c.EndsWith(")"))
    {
        c = "-" + c.SubString(1, c.Length - 2);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: This is not the way to change this. Formatting in the .NET Framework depends on the specif culture.

Comment: @WouterdeKort Could you explain why you think it wouldn't work? OP is aware of the culture-dependency, but would explicitly like brackets removed and '-' added, so how is it not a solution?

Comment: Because there are more elegant solutions. What if the culture is changed to a culture that doesn't use ( ) but [ ], then suddenly your code breaks while the solution of Tim Schmelter always works.

Comment: @WouterdeKort I agree with the underlying reasoning, but no cultures uses [ ] or any other brackets other than ( ). I know this is a hack, and that the other solution is more *proper*, but I don't think it's a wrong solution.